# Protractor - Unable to switch to twitter authorization pop-up from my angular js application

Tags: protractor

I am using Page object model where I am calling the below function written in a page_object.js from my spec. I have tried all possible ways but it always fails on switch. Please help

```
var Twitter_Actions = function (){  
this.authorizeAccount = function(username,pswd){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
      var popUpHandle = handles[1];
      expect(popUpHandle).toBeDefined();// Asrton to cnfrm pop-up is defined
      browser.switchTo().window(popUpHandle); // Failing on Switch
      var windowtitle = browser.getTitle().then(function(webpagetitle){
            return webpagetitle;
           });
      console.log(windowtitle);// Printing title on the console to debug
      browser.executeScript('window.focus();');

      element(by.name("session[username_or_email]")).sendKeys(username);
                element(by.name("session[password]")).sendKeys(pswd);
                element(by.id('allow')).click();                
          });        
      }
  }
```

Comment: I tried your function to authorize the twitter authorization pop-up that throws up on [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) website. Its working fine. You can see the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16d2c4d0af71a907dbe2f10e76232f4d)